# Get value from Jquery function

Tags: jquery, function

I have been trying to return the value of 'city' variable but i keep geeting weird results, i know there must be something wrong with my code, i hope you can help me figure out what it is.

```
function getCity(lat,lng)
{
var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=";
var sensor="&sensor=false";

var city;
$.getJSON(url+lat+","+lng+sensor,function(json)
    {
        var address=json.results[0].address_components;
        var addr;
        for(var i in address)
            {
                addr=address[i];
                if(addr.types[0] == "locality" && addr.types[1] == "political")
                {
                    city=addr.long_name;

                }
            }
      });
      return city;
}
```

Comment: There is an error before your first `return city`. I think it should read `city = addr.long_name` - you're missing the `=` .

Comment: Please post the JSON string sent by the server, and an example of your 'weird' results.

Comment: I think you should return immediately the value when your condition is satisfied.
You don't need to wait to finish the loop.

Comment: I think getcity can not return you exact result, because its asynchronous call (ajax), which will have result later... so you should pass callback which will perform operation...

Comment: @Mike W : There is nothing wrong with my JSON, i use `console.log(city);` next to `city=addr.long_name;` and i get the correct value.

Comment: @HossamOukli Hey you missed a ";" at the end of declaration of var `url`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.getJson is an async function, which means you are returning the city, then the success function is executed (if the call worked). What you want is to wait for the call to come back. Here's what I think is a nice way of doing this, using jquery deferred :

```
function getCity(lat,lng)
{
  var def = jQuery.Deferred(); 
var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
var sensor="&sensor=false";

var city;
$.getJSON(url+lat+","+lng+sensor,function(json)
    {
        var address=json.results[0].address_components;
        var addr;
        for(var i in address)
            {
                addr=address[i];
                if(addr.types[0] == "locality" && addr.types[1] == "political")
                {
                    city=addr.long_name;

                }
            }
        def.resolve(city);

      });
return def.promise();
}

$.when(getCity(40.714623,-74.006605)).then(function (city) {
 alert(city);   
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvWag/29/)

Comment: Deferred/Promise is baked in jQuery's ajax function. You don't need to create and resolve your own Deferred object.

Comment: @Phil-R: Working fine on `Fiddle`but my firebug returns this error:

`TypeError: jQuery.Deferred is not a constructor
var def = new jQuery.Deferred();`

Any suggestion?

Comment: try `var def = jQuery.Deferred();` without `new`

Comment: Yep, my bad, just do it without the new. I'll edit the post and fiddle.

Comment: Both Expressions are working i just had an old version of jquery, it's working know thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

getcity is using asynchronous call (getJSON), which will have result later... so you should pass callback which will perform operation

another option is use synchronous call

```
$.ajax({
  url: myUrl,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  data: myData,
  success: function(data) {
    //stuff
  }
});
```

but still i feel , you should not wait for result, because browser will be hanged till result ... so go with call back approach...

Answer (score 1):

getJSON is an asynchronous call. So you can't return a value from your `getCity` like a usual function. In your case `city` will be returned BEFORE getJSON returns any value. You need to work inside the callback function to use return value.

But you can take advantage of jQuery's deferred/promise so you don't need go deep into callback functions. You can try the code below;

```
function getCity(lat,lng) {
    var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=";
    var sensor="&sensor=false";

    return $.getJSON(url+lat+","+lng+sensor);
}

function onSuccess(json) {
    var address=json.results[0].address_components;
    var addr;
    var city;

    for(var i in address) {
        addr=address[i];
        if(addr.types[0] == "locality" && addr.types[1] == "political") {
            city=addr.long_name;
        }
    }

    // And do other stuff
}

function onfail() {
    // Do something if there is a server error with the getJSON
}

getCity(lat, lng).done(onSuccess).fail(onfail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't return `city` in your callback. Just assign it like this:
    city = addr.long_name;

Since it's still within the getCity scope it should return right.

**Update**

Change the way you request the data. Do it like this:

```
 $.getJSON(url+lat+","+lng+sensor).done(function(json){

           //Do your assignment here
 });
```

This is because it's an asynchronous call so you want it assigned after it's done.

Comment: I tried that but i get this error,
`TypeError: $.getJSON(...).done is not a function`
Please try to correct it.