# New JQuery.Deferred(); isn't a constructor

Tags: jquery

I asked a question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737191/get-value-from-jquery-function) yesterday, i got a good answer with this line of code `var def = new jQuery.Deferred();`  the code is working fine at jsfiddle.net, but my firebug says that `TypeError: jQuery.Deferred is not a constructor`, and with this code `var def = jQuery.Deferred();` it said `TypeError: jQuery.Deferred is not a function`

Comment: which is the version of jQuery used?

Comment: Both syntaxes (with or without `new`) are valid. Deferred objects were introduced in jQuery 1.5 a few eternities ago. Are you really using an older version?

Comment: You're spelling `Deferred` wrongly (at least in your title) :-)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I stand corrected: "The new operator is optional." http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Deferred` method was introduced with jQuery 1.5. Ensure that you're using at least that version of the library, and if not, upgrade.

Comment: @HossamOukli I'm not sure I follow. If you mean people visiting the site in their browsers, they'll get whatever version of jQuery you serve. If what you're working on is a platform that people install on their own servers, then roll the jQuery upgrade into the next update of the platform install package.

Comment: Never mind my bad, it's working now, i have two answer to accept ;).

Comment: @HossamOukli Glad to be of help!